# Flask Sqlalchemy model return different result by calling model.__dict__(sometimes show backrefs and sometimes don't)

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to get results from  a query and send it with `jsonify` to the client, I create a function that gets an instance of the model, use its '**dict**' attribute delete unused values like `'_sa_instance_state'` and then return new dictionary as a jsonified object to client.
Here is my code:

```
def display(Object):
        data= Object.__dict__.copy()
        del data['_sa_instance_state']
        return data`

user = User.query.first()

@app.route('/')
def main():
       return jsonify(display(user))
```

Sometimes i get this error

> TypeError: Object of type Admin is not JSON serializable

where admin is 
another `model` that has a backref in User model. 
and weird thing happens here, because sometime without changing anything I don't get the error. 
When i tried to find out what's happening in a jupyter notebook, I see that `__dict__` doesn't show the backrefs in `jupyter notebook` but sometimes it  show the backrefs when I call it from the flask app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `__dict__` on SQLAlchemy models. Yes, backreferences *may* be present, [depending on how you configured reference loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html), and so can other SQLAlchemy-specific information.

You could use [runtime introspection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html) to get the [`InstanceState` instance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState). You can then decide what to reflect in JSON and what should be ignored:

```
from operator import attrgetter
from sqlalchemy import inspect

def display(object, only_loaded=False):
    insp = inspect(object)
    assert insp.is_instance
    value = attrgetter('loaded_value' if only_loaded else 'value')
    return {
        name: value(attr) for name, attr in insp.attrs.items()
        if name not in insp.mapper.relationships
    }
```

The above uses the [`Mapper.relationships` namespace](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.relationships) to skip any related objects. Another way of handling related objects is to recursively turn those into dictionaries too:

```
def display(object, include_related=True, only_loaded=False, seen=None):
    insp = inspect(object)
    assert insp.is_instance
    value = attrgetter('loaded_value' if only_loaded else 'value')
    result = {
        name: value(attr) for name, attr in insp.attrs.items()
        if name not in insp.mapper.relationships
    }
    if include_related:
        if seen is None:
            seen = set()
        seen.add(id(object))
        for name, rel in insp.mapper.relationships.items():
            related = value(insp.attrs[name])
            if related is not None:
                if rel.uselist:
                    displays = result[name] = []
                    for r in related:
                        if id(r) in seen:
                            continue
                        displays.append(display(r, True, only_loaded, seen))
                else:
                    if id(related) in seen:
                        continue
                    result[name] = display(related, True, only_loaded)
    return result
```

but take into account that with bi-directional relationship objects you can quickly end up reflecting a much larger chunk of your database than you may have intended.

Personally, I find it easier to just add a `as_dict()` method to my models that produce the dictionary to reflect, or use a Flask add-on that [provides a reflection API](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html).